# Losing time zone in dataset

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

I have database table that contains a few TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE fields. I select the records from this table and put them in dataset. When I try to access the date/time fields, I seem to have lost the time zone info.
I tried adding the following before adapter.Fill():

```
adapter.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes = true;
```

But this causes all fields to be using Oracle data types, not just the date/time fields. For instance, I can no longer Convert.ToInt32(dr["SomeIntField"]) becuase it is now OracleDecimal.
Is there any way I can get the time zone info from my table into a dataset without messing up all other fields?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the ReturnProviderSpecificTypes with the following:

```
adapter.SafeMapping.Add("*", typeof(string));
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

This will convert the data to string type (only options are sting and byte[]). It seems to keep my time zone format which I can access using:

```
dtzTime = new OracleTimeStampTZ(dr["MY_DBTable_Column_with_TZ"].ToString());
```

I store my dates with USA/EASTERN, USA/PACIFIC, etc. time zones, so above returns:
26-FEB-2013 14:49:46.169030000 US/MOUNTAIN